# Is there a way to add Reattach and Unattach links in image gallery?

Tags: attachments, media-library

For some reason the Reattach and Unattach links in Media library is gone.
Is there a way to add these from functions.php?

Comment: Did you checked in Screen Options on the top, is Uploaded to is checked ?

Comment: Ah, didn't know there where any screen options for this page. But they are all checked (Author,Uploaded to,Comments,Date )